# Reusable UITableView or UITableViewController for multiple View controllers- Returns blank tableVC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to make ReusableVC that can be reused in my whole project?

I tried many times with uitableview controller, but my tableview delegates and data source not working from another class

Created tableView in VC and tried to load datasource from reusableVc also didn't worked

```
#import "FirstVC.h"
#import "ReTableViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ReTableViewController *reTableView=[[ReTableViewController alloc]init];
  // relod data doesnot call cell for row
//  [tableViewObj.tableView reloadData];
   [self.view addSubview:reTableView.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after hours of try i made it....i took my whole free saturday on it...now on one page i added two different array and filled with different data and it works!!

```
ReTableViewController *reTableView=[[ReTableViewController alloc]init];
    reTableView.dataArray=array;
    reTableView.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,200,reTableView.view.frame.size.width, reTableView.view.frame.size.height);
   [self addChildViewController:reTableView];
   [self.view addSubview:reTableView.view];
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[reTableView.tableView reloadData];});
    [reTableView.tableView reloadData];



    ReTableViewController *ReUseTableView=[[ReTableViewController alloc]init];
    ReUseTableView.dataArray=array2;
    ReUseTableView.view.frame=CGRectMake(160,200,ReUseTableView.view.frame.size.width, ReUseTableView.view.frame.size.height);
    [self addChildViewController:ReUseTableView];
    [self.view addSubview:ReUseTableView.view];
    [ReUseTableView.tableView reloadData];
```